# Ruby: How to persist w/o DBS or File.open()?

Tags: ruby, database, persistence

I'm working on a Gem that should persist some data for a certain time. Since I'd like to keep the dependencies of the Gem as shallow as possible I do not want to persist using a DBS like SQLite3. I want my users to be able to install my Gem simply by issuing:

```
gem install my_gem_name
```

On the other hand I have to persist structured data. So a lightweight DBS would be fine. What I do not want to do is something like File.open() and so I wonder if anyone knows a lightweight persistency layer in pure ruby that can be used for such a task.

I did not find any yet and looking forward to any reply.

Thx, Felix.

Comment: You haven't stated your requirements completely. Which set of operations you need to perform on persisted data? Querying? Why not File.open()? Why not YAML? Why not Marshal dump and restore? etc.

Comment: BTW, you are aware that your gem can specify dependencies which will be installed automatically when user issues `gem install your_gem`?

Comment: Mladen, of cause I know that I can install additional dependencies when it comes to Ruby Gems. I can't when it comes to things like SQLite3 for example. Marshalling data, dump, restore ... yes. I hoped there is some lightweight Gem that provides some nice and more abstract interface to that. I do not need query or search support. Simply storing and restoring data should be it.

Comment: [databank](https://github.com/adkron/data_bank) seems to be a good fit, even if I wish I could store more than one object. But for the next fellow to read this, have a look at it. Otherwise [storable](https://github.com/delano/storable/) looks nice too.

Comment: Both libraries seems to be barely thin wrappers around existing serialization methods in corelib. Not sure if they are worth introducing additional gem dependency IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should first consider several possibilities already in the corelib:

- [`Marshal#dump` and `load`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html)
- [`PStore`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/PStore.html)
- [`YAML`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/YAML.html)